# Trying To Add Onclick To Links, But Can't With .onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So I'm trying to use ajax to put content into a div, and trying to have it change all internal links before it adds the content so that they will use the funciton and load with ajax instead of navigating to another page. My function is supposed to get the data with ajax, change the href and onclick attributes of the link, then put it into the div... However, all it's doing is changing the href and not adding an onclick attribute at all. Here's what I was using so far:

```
function loadHTML(url, destination) {
    $.get(url, function(data){
        html = $(data);
        $('a', html).each(function(){
            if ( $.isUrlInternal( this.href )){
                this.onclick = loadHTML(this.href,"forum_frame"); // I've tried using both a string and just putting the function here, neither seem to work.
                this.href = "javascript:void(0)";
            }
        });
        $(destination).html(html);
    });
};
```

Also, I'm using jquery-urlinternal. Just thought that was relevant.

Comment: Sorry, was trying to put that bit in a code block, but it wouldn't go for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the effect you want with less effort by doing this on your destination element ahead of time:

```
$(destination).on("click", "A", function(e) {
   if ($.isUrlInternal(this.href)) {
      e.preventDefault();
      loadHTML(this.href, "forum_frame");
   }
});
```

Now any `<a>` that ends up inside the `destination` container will be handled automatically, even content added in the future by DOM manipulations.

Comment: This worked for me, with a little tweaking! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When setting a function to `onclick` through js it will not show on the markup as an attribute. However in this case it is not working because the function is not being set correctly. Easy approach to make it work,

```
....
var theHref=this.href;
this.onclick = function(){loadHTML(theHref,"forum_frame");}
....
```

simple demo http://jsbin.com/culoviro/1/edit

Comment: Trying to use this... but it doesn't seem to do the trick either. Nothing happens when links are clicked.

Comment: @Frayer just added an example for the sake of completion and validity